# cursor.execute works in scratch file but not in main file

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I'm trying to make a minigame bot using discord.py and sqlite3 as my database but the problem i'm encountering is that when I use the command !deathjoin which first checks if the user who did the command is already in the database using his/her discord id and then adds that person to the database but what's when it gets to

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?""",(ide,)) #ide=person's id
```

it stops running and what's more annoying is that when i tested if it had any syntax error by printing the id before and after

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?""",(ide,))
```

is run it only prints it before

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?""",(ide,))
```

runs but when i transfer it to a scratch file which also resides in the same directory as the main file/file im using it prints the id two times meaning

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?""",(ide,))
```

is correct.
code of !deathroll command in main file:

```
connect = sqlite3.connect('Deathroll_Bot3.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@client.command()
async def deathjoin(ctx):
    start_currency = 1000
    ide = ctx.author.id
    print("1st", ide)
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?""",(ide,))
    print("2nd",ide)
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    if len(data)<= 0:
        print("no data found: inserting data")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DEATHROLL (id,currency) VALUES (?,?)", (ide, start_currency))
        connect.commit()
        print("inserted data")
    else:
        await ctx.send("your already have an account")
```

full code of scratch file:

```
import sqlite3
connect = sqlite3.connect('Deathroll_Bot3.db')
cursor=connect.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEATHROLL(
                   id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                   currency INT NOT NULL

)""")
ide=798794654698764826
print("1st",ide)
cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?""",(ide,))
print("2nd",ide)
```

and yes i've made sure that i'm using the same table from the same database on both files and that both files are on the same directory

Answer (score 1):

It's because your variable `connect` is not a global variable you can either define it globally or you can declare it inside the function `deathjoin` and it should work

```
connect = sqlite3.connect('Deathroll_Bot3.db')
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@client.command()
async def deathjoin(ctx):
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    start_currency = 1000
    ide = ctx.author.id
    print("1st", ide)
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM DEATHROLL WHERE id=?""",(ide,))
    print("2nd",ide)
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    if len(data)<= 0:
        print("no data found: inserting data")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO DEATHROLL (id,currency) VALUES (?,?)", (ide, start_currency))
        connect.commit()
        print("inserted data")
    else:
        await ctx.send("your already have an account")
```